# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 (but only sometimes)

Tags: javascript, json

Ok, so this is just a part of my code, and actually works as it's supposed to.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "main.json", function(data) {
    return data;
});

var json;
window.onload = function() {
    var jsonTxt = jqxhr.responseText;
    json = JSON.parse(jsonTxt);
    ....
}
```

But every 10th attempt or so i get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at window.onload (profile.js:8)
```

It's really annoying, because it will leave my page blank. I do think it has something to do with me trying to parse the JSON wrong - or something. I really don't know and I'm looking forward to any kind of answer that could lead me to the fix. Thank you.

Comment: It's very likely a timing issue. if `onload` fires before `$.getJSON` finishes, then `responseText` won't be set to valid JSON. Maybe you want to do the parsing in the `success` callback (the third optional argument). Depends on what you want to do...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That unexpected "u" is the first letter of the string "undefined". It happens because your two asynchronous operations (i.e. loading the JSON and loading the window) are racing to completion, and if the JSON isn't loaded fast enough, the `window.onload` method will attempt to parse the JSON string that isn't loaded yet.

A solution is to move the JSON loading inside the `onload` even handler. Additionally, the whole point of `getJSON` is that it already parses the response for you as a JSON object, so there is no need for `JSON.parse()`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $.getJSON( "main.json", function(json) {
        // process the results here
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but i ended up getting unexpected u everytime, even though it console.logged it right. Could you try to give me an example of the "process the results here"? :/

Comment: "process the results here" is the part that in your original code would come after `json = JSON.parse(jsonTxt);`

Comment: Just tried that, none of the code inside the curly brackets work. Not even console.log("test");

Comment: Just tried it (with literally just the code I wrote up there, plus `console.log(json)` instead of the comment), and a "main.json" I wrote, worked for me. There's something else at play.

Comment: Ok.. so i literally did the same as before.. but now it works, i don't even know..

Comment: Well, the error still appears, but instead of 1/10th of the time, it now more like 1/100th time. So.. thank you! :)

Comment: That's still not really right, it shouldn't appear ever :) (provided of course that `main.json` is loaded successfully) Given what little context we have to go on here I can't say anything more specific though unfortunately. Just make sure you've got all your asynchronous operations in order, and don't run two of them at the same time if one depends on the result of the other.

Comment: Well, i seems to be working with no errors no. I don't even know what's happening. Just by playing around with my site, it fixed itself (lol?).

Answer (score 2):

Insert a try catch block where the JSON.parse() is called.

It is possible that the text itself is not JSON.

For example...

I think this is the issue because if response text is undefined, the char 'u' is at position 0. So JSON.parse() is working with a string. Not a javascript-object-notation text file.

```
if(response !== undefined){
    try{
    // do parse
    }
    catch(errror){
        console.error("Not a JSON response")
    }
}
```